# How to turn off "bonds" in chemmacros\chemformula?

Tags: chemmacros, chemformula

In `chemmacros`/`chemformula` a hyphen is replaced with a bond, and you have to put hyphens in quotes. I don't use the bond feature, as I use this to write out papers, rather then educational materials. Is there a way I can turn off the bond interface unless I specifically want it on for that formula (you see double or triple bonds in the names of papers once in a blue moon, so I'd like that feature accessible, just not the default).

Probably my shortest MWE ever:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{formula=chemformula} %chemformula, not mhchem or such

\begin{document}
\ch{UO2-H2O2 "-" K2CO3} %Note the bond vs hyphen
\end{document} %use chemformula instead of say, mhchem
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually rather easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\chemsetup{formula=chemformula}

\begin{document}

\ch{UO2-H2O2 "-" K2CO3}

\RemoveChemCompoundProperty{-}
\ch{UO2-H2O2 "-" K2CO3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to restrict the change you can either use grouping (`{...}` or `\begingroup...\endgroup`) or define the single bond again later with

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewChemCompoundProperty {-} { \chemformula_single_bond: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Because of the double role of `-` both as single bond and as minus sign using

```
\NewChemCompoundProperty{-}{\bond{single}}
```

won't suffice.

Comment: That was fast! Now if I want to turn it back on, can I do that? All of these will be in my .bib file, so it is hard to just put that command before the one I need.

Comment: @Canageek I edited the answer.

Comment: So I could so something like title = "{\RemoveChemCompoundProperty{-} \ch{...}}", and that would work?

Comment: @Canageek yes, it would